# Exposing redis to external clients

Tags: architecture, security, message-queue, redis, cloud

We are building a system that runs on our cloud and that needs information from our clients network that must not be exposed openly. We have concluded that the only way this could work, is if our clients can install an agent in their network, that would gather the required information and push it to our system through the internet.

This agent application, cannot communicate to our server using a regular RestAPI or webservice, because we have use cases that require us requesting specific information to the specific agent instances (a request to resync data from client 1 should only go to client 1's agent). We looked into gRPC streams and keep a stream open with every agent and just routes those requests to the stream, but since our backend has multiple instances, it would be hard to identify and reuse a single stream from different instances.

Then something that works for us, is using Redis streams and create a stream per agent, then our backend would only have to write to the specific agent redis stream (it would know the name of the stream as it would the agent/client identifier) from whichever of our instances.

The concern though, is the "over the internet" part.

Redis has TLS support since version 6, allows us to block certain commands (flushall for example) and supports defining users with access to only specific commands and keys/streams...

I understand exposing Redis over the internet or to any other network that not the one serving redis itself, has always been discouraged (AWS ElastiCache only allows access from within the same VPC/subnet for example). However, everything I find about redis security, say something in the lines of:

> Do not publicly expose the Redis server
> Since Redis has no default authentication, it does not support encryption. All data is stored in cleartext. An attacker can use FLUSHALL command to delete all key-value data sets...
> [Source](https://www.gspann.com/resources/blogs/best-practices-to-secure-redis-implementation-in-cloud-infrastructure/)

That type of statement holds very true to older versions of Redis that didn't provide TLS nor access control. But since those are now supported since version 6, am I crazy to go forward with this?

There's a concern about rate limiting, which is probably something that is not addressed by Redis itself, but that we can possibly find a solution with Kubernetes or network configuration in the cloud.

So, I know this is an unusual architecture and I am not the only one to [think about it](https://medium.com/@treeder/exposing-messaging-internals-to-the-outside-world-9eb8a9b886aa), but  I am just looking for your opinions on whether exposing Redis streams over the internet for my use case, considering the features that Redis now has, is that much of a security risk/ bad idea overall.

Comment: why not use your cloud providers message queue system?

Comment: Hi @ewan. I can't rely on tbe cloud provider's message queue because this solution needs to work both in the cloud and in on prem deployments (in the latter, of course, there would be no need to expose it to the internet)

Comment: replace out with a n other message queue?

Comment: Right now Redis is the only one that adds this type of security features, but whatever the case, I think the major concern here is about exposing the message q over the internet so that remote services can consumer and publish to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposing Redis to the Internet as a whole is generally a bad idea (as their documentation says).

However, exposing Redis over the Internet *to specific trusted IP addresses* is much less dangerous, especially if you have strong TLS encryption and strong authentication enforced. This should be done at the network/firewall level, rather than in Redis itself. If you can use client-certifiate authentication (also known as mutual TLS) rather than a username/password that would be even better.

Alternatively, would it be possible to send the Redis traffic over a VPN, to avoid exposing the service directly.

In this case, in order to exploit it an attacker would need to compromise one of the trusted IP addresses belonging to your clients, and then exploit either a Redis vulnerability or a set of stolen credentials.

It's still not an ideal architecture, but the real-world risk is likely to be relatively low.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gh0stFish!
Yes, I agree it is weird and sounds like a bad idea, but they have added features to make it more secure in the latest versions and those sound appealing. We are considering using a VPN, but that would make our solution a bit more expensive, even though is a very valid alternative.